hive mapping mysql table: can not succeed on selecting different mysql data source in join condition
I use jdbc storage handler to map multi mysql data sources in hive as https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/JDBC+Storage+Handler;
the first table is:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dim_order_right_detail(
  id bigint,
  right_detail_id string,
  open_id string,
  order_id string
) STORED BY 'org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcStorageHandler' 
LOCATION 'hdfs://hdp5/dpyy/prod/hive/dpyy_prod.db/dim_order_right_detail' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'hive.sql.database.type' = 'MYSQL',
  'hive.sql.jdbc.driver' = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
  'hive.sql.jdbc.url' = 'jdbc:mysql://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:3306/dpyy_vas?&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false',
  'hive.sql.dbcp.username' = 'XXXXX',
  'hive.sql.dbcp.password' = 'XXXXX',
  'hive.sql.query' = 'SELECT id,right_detail_id,open_id,order_id FROM order_right_detail',
  'hive.sql.dbcp.maxActive' = '1'
)

the other is:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dim_account_info(
     id bigint,
     open_id string,
     user_id string
) STORED BY 'org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcStorageHandler' 
LOCATION 'hdfs://hdp5/dpyy/prod/hive/plat_prod.db/dim_account_info' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'hive.sql.database.type' = 'MYSQL',
  'hive.sql.jdbc.driver' = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
  'hive.sql.jdbc.url' = 'jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306/dpyy_ucs?&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false',
  'hive.sql.dbcp.username' = 'dpyy_bigdata',
  'hive.sql.dbcp.password' = 'XXXXXXX',
  'hive.sql.query' = 'SELECT id,open_id,user_id FROM account_info',
  'hive.sql.dbcp.maxActive' = '1'
)

When I query single table, everything is ok, but I get an error when my query in join condition,the error is:
Table not found in dpyy_ucs.order_info 
or 
Table not found in dpyy_vas.account_info

it seems it can not support multi mysql data sources in hive 3.1.3, however, in hive 3.1.0 it works.
Can anyone give me any advice to solve this problem in hive 3.1.3?

I finally solved this problem by using hive material view, however, what makes me feel confused is that hive view did not work
